# Problems starting kafka (version 3.6.0), using windows

Tags: apache-kafka, git-bash

I am having some problems starting Kafka, I am using the command line

```
$ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

but the response I am getting is:

```
$ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
[0.004s][error][logging] Error opening log file '/c/spring-with-kafka/kafka_2.13-3.6.0/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log': No such file or directory exists
[0.004s][error][log] Initializing output 'file=/c/spring-with-kafka/kafka_2.13-3.6.0/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log' using options 'filecount =10,filesize=100M' failed.
Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc*:file=/c/spring-with-kafka/kafka_2.13-3.6.0/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log:time,tags:filecount= 10 ,file size=100M', see the error log for details.
Error: Could not create Java virtual machine.
Error: A fatal exception occurred. Program will exit.
```

I have tried other versions such as 3.6.1 but the error is the same, I am using the git bats console to execute the command lines.

What I can do?

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _I am using the git bats console to execute the command lines_ Don't you mean ___git bash console___ ?